# How to set the value of the option select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob question
I just want to set a value of an option in select tag via jQuery
I'm doing this:

HTML:

```
<select class="mySelect">
  <option value="">1</option>
  <option value="">2</option>
  <option value="">3</option>
  <option value="">4</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('select.mySelect:first-child').val("test");
```

This should set the value of the first option to "test", but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I even tried setting an id or class for the first option and selecting it like so $('optionID').val('test')

Comment: Please change `$('optionID').val('test')` to `$('#optionID').val('test')` and it would work.

Comment: it had the hash mark, was just typing too fast and missed it here )

Comment: apparantly your jquery is not running, where is the JS part of your code is placed at your HTML file? at the `head` tag or at the botoom of the `body` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select.mySelect :first-child').val("test");
// add a space ---^
```

Your selector was looking for a select element that *is* a first child, not the first child of a select element.

You would also need to ensure that that JS is executed after the element in question is parsed, so include it in a script element that appears after the select (putting your script just before the closing `</body>` tag is a common convention) and/or wrap it in a document ready handler.

Comment: Thanks, I knew its a noob question :)  Also I was looking for the value in view page source code instead of trying to log it in the console...

Comment: Ah, yes. As I guess you now know, the view page source option doesn't show any changes that were made to the page with JS, it just shows what the browser originally received from the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select.mySelect option:eq(0)').attr('value', 'myvalue');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `val()` to set a value to a select, jQuery searches for the the `<option>` and marks it as the selected choice. What you want to do is alter its 'value' attribute, which is what Adrian has done

```
$('select.mySelect option:eq(0)').attr('value', 'myvalue');
```

Comment: `.val()` works to set the value of option elements too, as long as you call it on a jQuery object that actually contains an option element rather than calling it on a select element.

Answer (score 1):

You can controll witch child to add value by `.eq()` like this:

`$('select.mySelect option').eq(0).val("test");`

Above code will select all options and filter through them to find the very first option. change it to `eq(1)` for the second option and so on.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zy974/

**ALSO**

press F12 on chrome and go to `Console` tab. Do you see any error there?